# FreeDOS as DOSBox replacement

Tags: qemu, linux-kvm, libvirt, freedos, virt-manager

Generally when the question about DOS games flares up, the general consensus is to use DOSBox (or DOSBox Staging) and it usually does the job.

However, as a proof of concept I wonder if it would be possible to use KVM/QEMU with libvirt and Virtual Machine Manager to do the same.

So far I have FreeDOS running and I have basic sound support (using "sb16" in the libvirt config).

However, two things I appear to not manage:

- adding my USB joystick(s) as regular non-USB joystick devices (e.g. game port)
- getting the system to adhere to the `BLASTER` variable for the sound

The joystick part is bothering me most, since some games are very cumbersome (or even impossible) to play without a joystick.  I was reading through the relevant [libvirt XML](https://libvirt.org/format.html) documents, but could not find a hint on how to do it.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_port), however, there used to be game port to USB adapters, which gives me hope that a conversion (even backwards) could be fairly straight-forward (maybe attaching "/dev/input/js#" somehow?).

My understanding of Sound Blaster 16 and DOS is that it does not need any specific drivers as long as the `BLASTER` variable is set for the card ("T6" for the SB16 as far as I know).  So, I set it up like this:

```
BLASTER=A220 I5 D1 H5 T6
```

However, the system uses "D5" instead, which leaves me puzzled.  I can direct games to use it that way as long as games have a setup and allow setting it up that way, but this feels like an awful workaround.  The MIDI on the sound card does not work either.  However, whether this is related or not, I do not know.  It may even be a limitation in the QEMU implementation of the SB16, but I am no programmer and did not fully understand the [C code](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/audio/sb16.c).

Comment: It doesn't need any specific drivers because each DOS-based game had *built-in* drivers for the sound cards it supported, and just directly did all the hardware I/O.

Comment: Not your fault at all : The C code in question is truly incomprehensible with absolutely no useful comments. I think this project of yours has little chance of success.

Comment: FWIW, I have a DOS 6 machine in VMware. DOS itself supports a Mouse (probably a compatible Joystick). The game I ran produced proper sound but did not use a mouse. Other of my games do support Mouse. So it varies as others have said.

Comment: @harrymc, "I think this project of yours has little chance of success."  It would be good to know how you came to this conclusion.  Otherwise this comment is understood as "I advise you to not even try." ;-)

Comment: @John, the sound FX is there with games supporting SB16 once set up to use "D5".  Just the (MIDI) music is not at all working and games produce errors trying to set it up.  Considering input devices: Yes, mouse and keyboard both work since QEMU translates them as PS/2 devices.  The USB joystick I have, however, would need to be translated into a game port device.  I have seen [USB-to-COM conversion](https://serverfault.com/questions/872238/qemu-and-serial-ports-on-the-guest-os), so I know that some things can be done with intelligent XML editing.